# Shorten directive in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, directive

I'm trying to use laravel component and slot.

As I'm using blade templates under `components` folder, my blade syntax is something like this

```
@component('components.button',['data'=>$data]) 
@endcomponent
```

Here, every times I call it, I have to write the word "component" multiple times.
can I shorten it as below?

```
@component('button',['data'=>$data])
```

If yes, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Remove the `components` folder and move all your views in the `views` directory.. this will create a mess, but you will feel no pain :D 

Use an IDE there is auto-completion that will help you.

Comment: Hi @nakov , this is an existing project from my work. There are many blade templates in "views" directory already. It will surely create a mess.

Comment: So that's why I said use an IDE which will help you with autocompletion, because there is no other way. That's the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use of ***Aliasing Components*** functionality

If your Blade components are stored in a sub-directory, you may wish to alias them for easier access. For example, imagine a Blade `component` that is stored at `resources/views/components/alert.blade`.php. You may use the component method to alias the component from `components.alert` to `alert`. Typically, this should be done in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
Blade::component('components.alert', 'alert');
```

[Referense](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots)